# With iPhone 7 and UIFeedbackGenerator, which system actions perform which kinds of taptic feedback?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios10, uifeedbackgenerator

(This question is mostly applicable to those of us developing iPhone apps without access to an iPhone 7.)

I want to incorporate the new taptic feedback available with the iPhone 7 into my apps, and I want to make sure my uses of it align properly with how iOS uses them at a system level. Without a device I can't test this.

Apple provides a document describing the different kinds of feedback: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/feedback/ Namely "Notification", "Impact", or "Selection".

For instance, in Mail.app, when you slide a cell to archive it, it gives taptic feedback. Which of those three above (and their corresponding "variation") does Mail.app use? I'm guessing "Selection" but may be wrong.

Bonus points for pulling down Notification Center or Control Center, as well as any others you can provide for reference, but the gestures in Mail.app would be an awesome start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out this article, it gives you an overview how UIFeedbackGenerator works. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-generate-haptic-feedback-with-uifeedbackgenerator

Alternatively, you can create a demo project and check out which feedback is best suited for your needs.

**Edit:**
It's the selection feedback for Mail app. The notification center uses multiple feedbacks depending upon the sliding. If you do it slowly, it's impact heavy and how if you do it a bit slowly, it's impact light and if you just slide it down immediately, it produces no feedback.

Comment: I don't think there's any other way to test without an iPhone 7.

Comment: I'm not asking how to test, I'm asking for someone who has an iPhone 7 and is able to test to answer the question as to which feedback mode is used in Mail.app gestures.

Comment: It's the selection feedback. Just tried on my iPhone 7.